# How to use popen() properly?

Tags: c, popen, simplehttpserver, gunzip

My program should simulate a simple httpServer replying to clients requests. It should answer both .html and .html.gz requests. My problem is when I receive a .gz request. Currently execute_script is handling that request and it unzips the file but I can't send it back to the client. What's the problem with my code?

```
void execute_script(int socket)
{

    FILE *gp;
    char temp[SIZE_BUF];

    // Searchs for page in directory htdocs
    sprintf(buf_tmp,"htdocs/%s",req_buf);
    sprintf(temp, "gunzip -k %s", buf_tmp);

    // Verifies if file exists
    if((gp=popen(temp,"r"))==NULL) {
        // Page not found, send error to client
        printf("send_page: page %s not found, alerting client\n",buf_tmp);

    }
    else {
        // Page found, send to client 

        while(fgets(buf_tmp,SIZE_BUF,gp)!=NULL)
            send(socket,buf_tmp,strlen(buf_tmp),0);

        // Close file
        pclose(gp);
    }



    return;
}
```

Comment: Most web-browsers today are capable of handling compressed files, with the correct headers sent. Also, why are you using two `sprintf` calls? One is really enough. Lastly, what do you mean by "I can't send it back to the client"? What happens when you call the function? What, if anything, is sent? Have you used some kind of debugging to see what is actually being sent (including headers)? Have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger? And why don't you have any error checking for the `send` call?

Comment: What I mean is when I make a request from the browser I don't get an answer from the server. For example if I make this request localhost:1080/index.html.gz, the only thing that happens is unzipping the file but it doesn't send it back

Comment: The program runs without any errors nor warnings

Comment: "*without any errors nor warnings*" not testing for failure, results in the impression there were no errors. You definitely want to test the result of `send()` (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html) for failure or success. And BTW, `fget()` *could* fail as well.

Comment: I tested both functions and they seemed to be working just fine